# Visual Studio crashes when trying to assign DataTemplate to WPF Window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, datatemplate

I'm a relative novice when I comes to WPF, but I'm trying to create a reusable template for my Windows.  The end goal is to have a template that can be applied to all dialog windows in my application, with customizable content.  Ultimately I want the template to permit *two* different sections of content.

Piecing together snippets from other web solutions this is what I have so far:

A `DataTemplate` in my Application.xaml file.  Still crude since I'm just trying to get it work:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="myDialogTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="OK"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Cancel"/>
            <Border Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=Elt2}" />
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=Elt1}" />
            </Border>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then in my Window xaml I assign this DataTemplate to the Window and insert an `ItemsControl`:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300" 
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDialogTemplate}" >

<ItemsControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Elt1">
        <Button>Stuff</Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Elt2">
        <Button>Stuff 2</Button>
    </ContentControl>

</ItemsControl>
```

So the idea as far as I understand it, is the `ContentPresenters` should route to the `Elt1` and `Elt2` Buttons laid out in the `ItemsControl`.  *Sometimes* this actually will run and display as desired.  But other times I get an error when opening my Application.xaml file on the `ContentPresenter` lines:

```
You need to set Binding.Path for a TwoWay Binding using ElementName or RelativeSource on a Content Property.
```

If I chance the `Mode` to something other than `TwoWay` the error still appears.  Also, everytime I open the xaml file of that particular Window in Visual Studio, designer freezes then crashes.  No idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here are a little... well, unconventional.

First thing: When binding with `ElementName=xyz`, you need to specify the property to which you are binding, this is the path. You cannot bind to the object itself, i.e. to the `ContentControl`s with names `Elt1/2`.

A binding with with `ElementName` needs to specify a path, i.e.:

```
Content="{Binding ElementName=Elt1, Path=Content}"
```

or

```
Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=Elt1}"
```

which are identical.

Secondly, your use the `Window`s `ContentTemplate` is kind of mixed up. The content template is used to specify how to render data, which is `raw` which means not `UIElements`. Say you have a class

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string Hello { get; set; }
    public string World { get; set; }
}
```

and you set an instance of this as the Window's `Content`, it will be displayed as

```
Namespace.MyModel
```

which is useless, so you use a template to specify how to render the data:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hello}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding World}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

There is no real point in using a template here, at all:

You can simply do this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300" 
ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDialogTemplate}" >

<DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="OK"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Cancel"/>

        <Border Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <ContentControl x:Name="Elt2">
                <Button>Stuff</Button>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <ContentControl x:Name="Elt1">
                 <Button>Stuff</Button>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Unless you've simplified the code for the sake of simplicity and there is more to it than I can see, there is no need here to make things complicated.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to do. Templates are not the right way to go here, as a template is for 'templating', or rendering, non-UI data.

The WPF tool for creating reusable arrangements of controls, is the *WPF UserControl*. In WPF you can really think of a *UserControl* as of a reusable grouping of UIElements, rather than a completely new control. On the UserControl you can define dependency properties for the two contents which get rendered accordingly. Try this:

Define a UserControl (named Dialog, for example):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.Dialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="OK"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Cancel"/>
        <Border Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:Dialog}}" />
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:Dialog}}" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Read the bindings like this: Set the content of the content presenters to the property named `Content1` of the first parent element of the content presenter which is of type `Dialog`.

And the code behind:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Dialog.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Dialog
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Content1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content1", typeof (UIElement), typeof (Dialog), new PropertyMetadata(default(UIElement)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Content2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content2", typeof (UIElement), typeof (Dialog), new PropertyMetadata(default(UIElement)));

    public UIElement Content1
    {
        get { return (UIElement) GetValue(Content1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Content1Property, value); }
    }

    public UIElement Content2
    {
        get { return (UIElement) GetValue(Content2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Content2Property, value); }
    }

    public Dialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<views:Dialog>
    <views:Dialog.Content1>
         <Button>Stuff</Button>
    </views:Dialog.Content1>
    <views:Dialog.Content2>
         <Button>Stuff 2</Button>
    </views:Dialog.Content2>
 </views:Dialog>
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: sorry I think I didn't explain well.  I wanted to create a reusable template for all dialog windows, such that I wouldn't have to redeclare the ok button, the cancel button, the border, etc for every window.  Of course it is not much trouble to retype these snippets, but I figured the "proper" way was to somehow dump these into a template that would then be used for every dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

Window.Content's value is the first item that is being placed inside Window. In your case it is the ItemsControl instance. So you are ending up placing a template for ItemsControl.

I have a feeling you want to template your buttons, right?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDialogTemplate">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>


<ItemsControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Elt1">
        <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDialogTemplate}">Stuff</Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="Elt2">
        <Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDialogTemplate}">Stuff 2</Button>
    </ContentControl>
</ItemsControl>
```

I hope this helps you any futher.

Comment: I think the requirement is to have different backgrounds in the content presenters...? But maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: I tried to add a better explanation.  I want to create a template for the Windows, but the template will have two different sections for content... and each section could be anything... button, grid, whatever.